# How to aggregate data to nested array output

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

So I have the following data in a collection

> { "UID" : 567, "AN0" : 100, "AN1" : 150, epoch:1401399336437 } 
>   { "UID" : 123, "AN0" : 200, "AN1" : 250, epoch:1401399336438 } 
>   { "UID" : 567, "AN0" : 300, "AN1" : 350, epoch:1401399336439 } 
>   ...

For UID:567 && AN0 I want to get an output similar to:

> { key : "AN0",
>     values: [
>     [1401399336437,  100 ]
>     [1401399336439,  300 ]
>     ]
>   }

I already more or less did it using GROUP like the following:

```
db.Datasets.group({ 
      cond: {UID: "567", AN0:{$exists:true}, epoch:{$exists:true}},
      initial: {key:"", values: []}, 
      reduce: function(obj, prev){ 
        var temp =[];
        temp.push(obj.epoch);
        temp.push(obj.AN0);
        prev.values.push(temp);
      },
      finalize: function(result){
          result.key = "AN0";
      }
})
```

However this method gave me alot of issues when sharing the scope with the reduce and finalize functions.

**So I would like to do the same with the aggregation pipeline**

I tried

```
db.Datasets.aggregate( [ 
    {$match:{ UID: "567" , AN0: {$exists:true} }}, 
    {$group : { _id: "$UID", value1:  { $push:  "$epoch"}, value2:  { $push:  "$AN0"} }},
] )
```

I get

> { value1:[ 1401399336437, 1401399336439 ],
>     value2:[ 100, 300 ]

How do change that to get

> value: [
>     [1401399336437,  100 ]
>     [1401399336439,  300 ]
>     ]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me I would do the aggregation just a little differently and then post process the result.

```
var res = db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$UID",
        "value": { 
            "$push": {
                "a": "$epoch", "b": "$AN0"
            }
        }
    }}
]).toArray()
```

At this stage the results look like this:

```
[
    { "_id" : 123, "value" : [ { "a" : 1401399336438, "b" : 200 } ] },
    { "_id" : 567, "value" : [ { "a" : 1401399336437, "b" : 100 }, { a" : 1401399336439, "b" : 300 } ]}
]
```

Now just transform:

```
var res = res.map(function(doc) { 
    doc.value = doc.value.map(function(x){ 
        return [x.a,x.b] 
    }); 
    return doc;
})
```

But if you are really determined to do this and have MongoDB 2.6 available, there is always this way as well:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$UID",
        "val": { 
            "$push": {
                "a": "$epoch", "b": "$AN0"
            }
        }
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "value": {
            "$map": {
              "input": "$val",
              "as": "el",
              "in": {
                  "$map": {
                      "input": { "$literal": ["A","B"] },
                      "as": "type",
                      "in": {
                          "$cond": [
                              { "$eq": [ "$$type", "A" ] },
                              "$$el.a",
                              "$$el.b"
                          ]
                      }
                  }
              }
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

The trick here in in the inner [**`$map`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) statement. Essentially, this is going to return an array, specified as a literal `["A","B"]` for the source input. So simply as the "outer" $map processes each element of the array created from [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/), the "inner" $map operation processes each "A" or "B" and tests the value.

In the [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operation, if that current value is "A" then return the already held variable for the outer array element as it's "a" key value, otherwise return the "b" key value. In a nutshell replace each element in the "outer" with the replaced form of the "inner". Rather than a document with keys you now have arrays within an array.

The output in either case is how you want it:

```
[
    {
            "_id" : 123,
            "value" : [
                    [
                            1401399336438,
                            200
                    ]
            ]
    },
    {
            "_id" : 567,
            "value" : [
                    [
                            1401399336437,
                            100
                    ],
                    [
                            1401399336439,
                            300
                    ]
            ]
    }
]
```

Comment: You seem quite experienced judging by the 2nd solution. Is this solution faster than a mapReduce implementation? The reason I want the data in this format is for the NVD3 graphing library to avoid re-processing the data in the client.

Comment: @opcode Much faster. MapReduce and other operations like group rely on JavaScript processing, as this needs to run through an interpreter it is much slower than the aggregation pipeline which is implemented in native code.